# How to get rid of Emotion UI which is drastically slowing down my Huawei Y330-U11?

Tags: rooting, updates, huawei-ascend-y330

I have Huawei Y330-U11 which performs sluggishly  due to Emotion UI installed by Huawei (I concluded it to be the reason because other phones having similar specifications but native Android UI works quite well).

Can anyone let me know how to get rid of Emotion UI? And, how to root and upgrade to Lollipop?

Answer (score 1):

1. Flash custom recovery (mine is CWM) with SB Flashtool.
2. Reboot your phone into recovery mode.
3. Flash root.zip.

Google for more details on flashing.